# Travelling wave at angle

Tags: math, trigonometry, coordinate

I've been trying for the longest time to figure this out but nothing seems to work.

I'm bascially trying to make a travelling wave with an arbitrary velocity.

In general what I've been trying to use is something involving the plane wave equation which goes like this when you have a `Vector velocity` and a `Point position`:

```
float pi2 = 2 * PI;

// For our purposes lambda is the speed
float lambda = velocity.length();

// Therefore frequency is 1
float frequency = 1.0F;

// Making angular frequency equal to 2 * PI
float omega = pi2;

// Lambda is the wavelength and pi2 / lambda is the wave number
Vector waveVector = velocity.norm().multiply(pi2 / lambda);

// Theta is the angle from the origin to the new position at time
float theta = waveVector.dot(position.toVector()) - (omega * time);

// Here's where I'm stuck. Psi is equal to the current disturbance of the wave.
// Where do I go from here to get the new coordinates?
float psi = amplitude * cos(theta);
```

Tested in 1 dimension and this works of course. Where

`float x = speed`

and

`float y = amplitude * cos((waveNumber * position.x) - (omega * time))`

That much makes sense to me. But for 2 dimensions I get stuck at psi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2D plane wave equation has an analytical solution using the coordinate vector in place of the scalar coordinate for the 1D case.

The solution is given by [an equation on this page](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/pasp/Solving_2D_Wave_Equation.html), where the underlines indicate a vector.